# How to Subclass WinAPI ListView to modify its drawing

Tags: c++, listview, winapi

I am trying to create a `ListView` class that essentially wraps the WINAPI `ListView` control. I am succeeded in putting everything in the class and subclassing the `WNDPROC`; however, I cannot figure out how to modify its look. I know that it is possible to us OwnerDraw or CustomDraw, but I believe that these messages are sent to the parent window. I would like to be able to keep all the drawing code within my`ListView` class without having to catch the message in the parent window and reflect it to the class. Is there a way to essentially hop into the `WM_PAINT` of the `ListView` control? I really don't want to (and don't really know how to) write everything from scratch. Here is my list view class:

```
 //ListView Class 
    #pragma once
    class ListView
    {
    private:
        int x, y;
        int w, h;
        int itemCount;
    
        int columnCount;

        bool mouseTracking;
    
        HWND listViewHandle;
        HWND parentWindow;
        HFONT lvFont;
    
       
        static LRESULT CALLBACK listViewProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData);
    public:
        ListView();
    
        BOOL Create(HWND parentWND, int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height, DWORD styles, HINSTANCE hInstance, HMENU hMenu);
    
        void SetPosition(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height);
        void SetColumnWidth(int index, int width);
    
        BOOL CreateColumn(int width, int index);
        BOOL InsertItems(int numItems);
        BOOL ClearItems();
        BOOL EraseItem(int index);
    
    
        //getters & setters
        BOOL SetFont(HFONT font);
    
        inline int getX() { return x; }
        inline int getY() { return y; }
        inline int getW() { return w; }
        inline int getH() { return h; }
        inline int getItemCount() { return itemCount; }
        inline int getColumnCount() { return columnCount; }
        inline HWND getHendle() { return listViewHandle; }
        inline HWND getParentHandle() { return parentWindow; }
    
    };


ListView::ListView()
: mouseTracking(false)
{}

//TO CONSIDER: Do I want all these arguments? Even X, Y, W, & H?
BOOL ListView::Create(HWND parentWND, int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height, DWORD styles, HINSTANCE hInstance, HMENU hMenu)
{
    parentWindow = parentWND;
    x = xPos;
    y = yPos;
    w = width;
    h = height;

    //CreateListView
    listViewHandle = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW, L"", styles, x, y, w, h, parentWindow, hMenu, hInstance, NULL);

    SetWindowSubclass(listViewHandle, listViewProc, 0, (DWORD_PTR)this);

    if (listViewHandle)
            return TRUE;
        return FALSE;
    }
    
    void ListView::SetPosition(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height)
    {
        x = xPos;
        y = yPos;
        w = width;
        h = height;
        SetWindowPos(listViewHandle, HWND_TOP, xPos, yPos, width, height, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    }
    
    
    LRESULT CALLBACK ListView::listViewProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
    {
    ListView* listView = reinterpret_cast<ListView*>(dwRefData);
    
        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
        {
            OutputDebugStringA(std::to_string(LOWORD(lParam)).c_str());
            OutputDebugStringA(" , ");
            OutputDebugStringA(std::to_string(HIWORD(lParam)).c_str());
            OutputDebugStringA("\n");
            return 0;
        }
    
        case  WM_MOUSEMOVE:
            if (!listView->mouseTracking)
            {
                // start tracking if we aren't already
                TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
                tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
                tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
                tme.hwndTrack = hWnd; //This is the handle to the ListView window
                tme.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;
                listView->mouseTracking = TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
            }
            break;
        case  WM_MOUSELEAVE:
            listView->mouseTracking = FALSE;
            break;
        case WM_NOTIFY:
            switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)
            {
            case NM_CUSTOMDRAW:
                OutputDebugStringA("CUSTOM DRAW\n");
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


void ListView::SetColumnWidth(int index, int width)
{
    SendMessage(listViewHandle, LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH, index, width);
}

BOOL ListView::CreateColumn(int width, int index)
{
    LVCOLUMN lvc;
    lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH  | LVCF_SUBITEM;
    // Initialize LVITEM members that are common to all items.

    // Initialize LVITEM members that are different for each item.
    lvc.iSubItem = 0;
    lvc.cx = 200;
    // Insert items into the list.
    if (ListView_InsertColumn(listViewHandle, index, &lvc) == -1)
        return FALSE;
    return TRUE;
}
BOOL ListView::InsertItems(int numItems)
{
    itemCount += numItems;

    LVITEM lvI;
    // Initialize LVITEM members that are common to all items.
    lvI.pszText = LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK; //This should send an LVN_GETDISPINFO message
    lvI.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_STATE;
    lvI.stateMask = 0;
    lvI.iSubItem = 0;
    lvI.state = 0;

    // Initialize LVITEM members that are different for each item.
    for (int index = 0; index < numItems; index++)
    {
        lvI.iItem = index;
        lvI.iImage = index;

        // Insert items into the list.
        if (ListView_InsertItem(listViewHandle, &lvI) == -1)
            return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL ListView::ClearItems()
{
    for (int i = itemCount; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        ListView_DeleteItem(listViewHandle, i);
    }
    itemCount = 0;
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL ListView::EraseItem(int index)
{
    ListView_DeleteItem(listViewHandle, index);
    itemCount--;
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL ListView::SetFont(HFONT font)
{
    return SendMessage(listViewHandle, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)font, TRUE);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways of doing that.

First, you can implement message reflection (similar to what MFC does) in the parent window. Here is an example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/744603/Custom-Controls-in-Win-API-Encapsulation-of-Cust

Second (may be simpler) way is to implement another "parent" window in your `ListView` class that will host a list control and process all custom drawing messages.

Comment: What type of window should I make it's parent?

Comment: Just a window; you can register a class with `RegisterClassEx` and then use its `lpszClassName` (that you specified) in a call to `CreateWindow`. Just like you probably did for your main window.